# Is the Canadian Securities Course (CSC) enough to get started in the finance industry in Canada?

Tags: canada, career

Would a CSC (Canadian Securities Course) certificate be enough to get started in the Canadian finance industry?

Comment: In what capacity? It's a big industry.

Comment: Eventually, I would like to get into Wealth Management.. Just want to get my foot in the door (as a trader?) to learn the industry from the inside..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia says "The Canadian Securities Course (CSC) offered by the Canadian Securities Institute (CSI) is the initial course required for becoming licensed to work within the Canadian securities industry (outside Quebec) as a securities dealer or securities agent."

Src: [Candian Securities Course](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Securities_Course)

EfficientMarket Canada adds " You require it and further courses for other jobs in the investment industry. Generally some work experience is also required. All of this is governed by various self-regulatory agencies.

The material in the course is strong on money making products, and fairly weak on material that would actually protect a consumer from harm. Passing the course is very little indication that you understand what's important about investing, for example, you won't be taught much of anything about the theory of investment, or the markets, or things like the efficient market hypothesis."

Src: [EfficientMarket.ca on the CSC](http://www.efficientmarket.ca/article/Canadian_Securities_Course)

So it appears that the CSC is **necessary** to work as certain types of financial agencies. That being said, I doubt it will be enough to get your foot in the door. This seems more like a prerequisite rather than a true qualification, so you'll be competing with MBAs/Finance students and other people who either have experience or training in the financial industry.

I'd recommend you look into the Chartered Financial Analyst (CFA) certification as that will provide you with a rigorous knowledge of financial theory as well as asset management, which seems more appropriate for what you'd like to do. From there you'll have to network like crazy and leverage your experience to get in at a Canadian financial firm and eventually wealth management. So yes, I suppose a CSC is a good first step but more will certainly be required and I doubt it will be enough to land you a full time position.

Another important factor is age - nobody expects undergrads to have extensive certifications or experience, but it's harder for a 35 year old to enter a new industry, especially finance.

Comment: I suggest you provide a link to any sources you cite.  Thank you.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea Thanks for the heads up - I edited them in!